# Raycast only returns false, even when true expected

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following `FollowingNPC` game object, which is supposed to follow the `Player` object if there is direct vision:

[image: FollowingNPC]

Here the `Player` object:

[image: Player]

The `BlockingLayer` and `Player` Layers have the physics collision enabled between each other:

[image: Collision Matrix]

The `FollowingNPC` hast the following script attached, that always returns a "Not Hit" result: Raycast always false. This is not the expected output, as both objects seem to have a clear view between each other and the debug ray can be drawn without problems.

```cs
public class FollowingNPC : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 heading, direction;
    private float distance;

    void Update()
    {
        heading = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position - transform.position;
        distance = heading.magnitude;
        direction = heading / distance;

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, direction, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.transform== GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform)
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * distance, Color.red);
                Debug.Log("Hit Player");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * distance, Color.yellow);
                Debug.Log("Hit Wall");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * distance, Color.white);
            Debug.Log("Not Hit");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Solved:**

As [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) suggested, Physics2D.Raycast should be used here. This function does not return a bool, so this is the implementation that worked for me:

```cs
void Update()
{
    heading = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position - transform.position;
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, heading.normalized, LayerMask.GetMask("Player"));

    if (hit.collider != null)
        if (hit.transform == GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform)
            Debug.Log("Hit Player");
        else
            Debug.Log("Hit Wall");
    else
        Debug.Log("Not Hit");
}
```

Also, it's important to note that, even with the mask, the Raycast returned the hit with the collider of `FolloginNPC`, so I had to disable it. I'll have to do some investigation or search a workaround.

Comment: Do you mean `Raycast` and `false`? Raytracing is used in lightning systems and not related to what you are talking about ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in Unity the `Physics` and `Physics2D` are completely independent and separated [Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsSection.html) engines!

> - Built-in 3D physics (Nvidia PhysX engine integration)
> - Built-in 2D physics (Box2D engine integration)

You have `Rigidbody2D` and `Collider2D` so you would rather want to use [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)!

You should also strongly avoid using `FindGameObjectWithTag` in `Update` and even worse multiple times as it is quite expensive! Rather do it **once** and store the result.

```c#
// If possible and best would be to already reference it via the Inspector
[SerilaizeField] private Transform player;

// As fallback get it ONCE on runtime
private void Awake()
{
    if(!player) player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

void Update()
{
    // actually those wouldn't really need to be fields
    heading = player.position - transform.position;
    distance = heading.magnitude;
    // This line isn't really necessary
    // If something I would use 
    //direction = heading.normalized
    direction = heading / distance;

    var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction);

    if (hit.collider)
    {
        if (hit.transform == player)
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * distance, Color.red);
            Debug.Log("Hit Player");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * distance, Color.yellow);
            Debug.Log("Hit Wall");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * distance, Color.white);
        Debug.Log("Not Hit");
    }
}
```

Later you should also remove all these `Debug.Log` since they are also quite expensive when done in `Update`!

Comment: This answer didn't solve the problem, but helped to find the right direction. I'll edit the question with more info about it.

Comment: @Pepv updated the answer ;) you shouldn't put solutions into the question ;)

Comment: Thanks! As you can see I'm not really used to Stack Overflow... As additional info: the ray collides with the collider of FollowingNPC, the solution that I found for this was simply to select the layer "Ignore Raycast" for this object. I also tried to use a mask on Raycast() without luck.